# How to refresh streambuilder in firestore query?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to create a list of cards, those cards take information from Firestore a query (need `.where`) it all worked out until I passed my quota, a bit later I found out about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lb-Pnytoi-8. I need to read specific documents with `.where` and post them in a streambuilder, I've thought of multiple options (mostly around Future, JSON) which non of them worked. I've theoretically thought of somehow pausing a streambuilder and reenabling it every pull-to-refresh or making a quota through a futurebuilder but I had no luck.

Here's my code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqzCD.png)

I couldn't find an efficient way to do this, any luck anyone?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the link to an image of your code, and place the absolute minimal code necessary to duplicate the problem into your question. See "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apologies for this question. For community members who seek the same answer: using methods such as `initState`, `async` or anything alike will cause the widget to rebuild - ergo send once more an API-request.

Comment: Please don't use answers to try to communicate, they're for solutions only. Simply delete your question if you don't like it. Flesh out the answer and select it if you know the solution.